# Event handling between views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

Ok I have a layout like the one in this pic:

[image: Layout]

The table in the upper part of the screen is made by:

*MessageListView*

```
define(['backbone','collections/messages','views/message'], function(Backbone, MessageCollection, MessageView) {
    var MessageListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#messagesContainer', 
        initialize: function() {

            this.collection = new MessageCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
            this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );

            this.table = this.$el.find("table tbody");
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.collection.each( function(message, index) {                
                this.renderMessage(message, index);
            }, this);
        },
        renderMessage: function(message, index) {
            var view = new MessageView({
                model:message,
                className: (index % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd"    
            });
            this.table.append( view.render().el );
        }
    });
    return MessageListView;
});
```

*MessageView*

```
define(['backbone','models/message'], function(Backbone, MessageCollection, MessageView) {
    var MessageView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template( $("#messageTemplate").html() ), 
        render: function() {
            this.setElement( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );          
            return this;
        },
        events:{
            'click':'select'
        },
        select: function() {
           // WHAT TO DO HERE?
        }
    });
    return MessageView;
});
```

*AppView*

```
define(['backbone','views/messages'], function(Backbone, MessageList) {
    var App = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            new MessageList(); 
        }
    });
    return App;
});
```

I will soon add a new view (maybe "PreviewView") in the lower part of the screen.

**I want to make something happen inside the "PreviewView" when user clicks a row.**

For example, it could be interesting to display other model's attributes (details, e.g.) inside the PreviewView.

What is the best practice?

- holding a reference to PreviewView inside each MessageView ?
- triggering events inside select method, and listening to them using *on()* inside the preview view.
- using a transient "selected" attribute in my model, and make PreviewView listen to collection "change" events?

Thank you, if you need more details tell me please, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about the best practice but I found this solution trivial to implement. I created a global messaging object, bus, whatever:

```
window.App = {};
window.App.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

You have to register the "triggerable" functions of PreviewView on the previously created event bus (according to your example, this should be in the `PreviewView`):

```
initialize: function () {
    App.vent.on('PreviewView.show', this.show, this);
}
```

Now you should be able to trigger any of registered events from anywhere within your application by calling: `App.vent.trigger`. For example when the user click on a row you will have something similar:

```
App.vent.trigger('PreviewView.show');
```

in case if you have to send and object along with the triggered event use:

```
App.vent.trigger('PreviewView.show', data);
```

Comment: ok but how about passing it the model selected. How can PreviewView know what model on the collection is selected? Maybe I can pass on the event bus the model itself?

Comment: sure, trigger also accepts argument: App.vent.trigger('PreviewView.show', model);

Comment: in your opinion, is it better to keep the application view (top level one) unaware of what the underlying view are doing and use an event aggregator as you suggested to keep all views decoupled.... OR have collections and all thing in the Application view?

Comment: I'm always going with decoupled views but it really depends on you, both coupling and decoupling have their pros and cons. In case of decoupled views you gain readability but in case of a general mistake maybe you have to correct the same error in every view. Best is to try both solutions and stick with the one you like most.