# Creating a sidebar using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I  want to create a sample page using backbone.js and i am completely new to it.

The view should be similar to the shown in backbone.js website where you have a sidebar and on the right side you have a content.
As shown in this link:-

http://backbonejs.org/

Consider the following scenario:-

```
    var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
       data:[
          {'title': 'Apple', 'logo':'images/apple.png', 'history': "Some history about       apple"},
           {'title': 'Google', 'logo':'images/google.png', 'history': "Some history about       google"},
           {'title': 'Microsoft', 'logo':'images/mirosoft.png', 'history': "Some history about microsoft"} 
]
       ]
    });
```

Now in my view the sidebar should contains links in list form like

```
<a href="#apple">Apple</a>
<a href="#google">Google</a>
<a href="#microsoft">Microsoft</a>
```

and on the right side, I want to see apple logo and history which passed in the data above.

Similarly when somebody clicks on google on the runtime, I change the content on right side of sidebar

Any guidance on how to get this..?

Answer (score 1):

See the answer below to get the basic idea about passing parameters between views:

[Event handling between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589186/event-handling-between-views)

Basically, you have to register an event which when fired, will re-display your main content:

```
ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function () {
       App.vent.on('show', this.show, this);
   },
   show: function (company) {
       // do something with your model, then call render()
   }
   // ....
});
```

and a sidebar view which is supposed to trigger that event when you click on any of the links:

```
SidebarView = Backbone.View.extend({
   events: {
      '.companylink click': 'clicked'
   },
   clicked: function (company) {
       App.vent.trigger('show', company);
   }
   // .....
});
```